# Will my pure clothes become impure by washing them in a washing machine with impure clothes?

Tags: taharah, clothing, najis

I wash all my clothes and bedsheets together, whether pure or impure, in a washing machine.  Will all pure clothes become impure?

Comment: Isn't the washing machine meant to pure impure clothes? Are the impure things still impure when you wash them?

Comment: Yes...they r impure...

Comment: Could you provide references that clothes still are impure when the are being washed in a washing machine, which purpose is to clean, therefore the name "washing machine"?

Comment: What??? I DONT UNDERSTAND...

Comment: Why do you think the clothes still are impure when you wash them?

Comment: I washed my pure clothes with impure clothes, will My pure clothes also become impure???

Comment: No! Because a washing machine is often cleaning impure clothes. Meaning, if you wash impure things and they become pure, why wouldn't pure things become pure after being washed with impure clothes? You understand?

Comment: No....please tell me more easily

Comment: If bad becomes good... then logically good should more likely become good..

Comment: Will they be pure or not???...Just a yes or no...

Comment: I have already said no. I mean NO they are not impure. I.e yes they are pure

Answer (score 1):

[SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2014/11/05/impurities-in-washing-machines-shafii-school/) describes two opposite opinions on this matter:

1. They become pure:

   > A machine will rinse the laundry multiple times after washing it with detergent. Those who hold that the clothes are rendered pure consider this rinsing to fulfill the requirement of the school to have the water poured on the impure entity (in this case, all of the clothes).

   Fatawa by AboutIslam ([1](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/acts-of-worship/washing-machine-purify-clothes/), [2](http://aboutislam.net/counseling/ask-the-scholar/miscellaneous-ask-the-scholar/a-dogs-impurity-and-washing-machines/)), Darul Ifta (sourced via [IslamQA.org](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulifta-deoband/24953)), [Darul Uloom Trinidad & Tobago](https://darululoomtt.net/washing-polluted-clothes/), [Darul Ifta Australia](http://www.fatwa.org.au/washing-clothes-in-washing-machine.html), [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/02/09/how-do-i-wash-my-clothes-properly-to-ensure-that-filth-doesnt-spread/), and [AskImam](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/19127) concur with this first opinion.
2. They become impure:

   > Those who hold that the clothes remain impure do not consider this rinsing sufficient in fulfilling that requirement. It considers the water and the clothes to have become impure.

   Fatawa by [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=E&Id=83760) and [MuftiOnline](http://muftionline.co.za/node/24542) follow this opinion; IslamWeb says one should pour pure water over the impurities first.

It seems the first opinion is more common.

Answer (score 0):

No once its washed, it all becomes pure. It does not matter if some were impure or pure. Washing it with water makes it pure.

Answer (score -1):

Just to note, semen is not considered najis (impure). And water is enough to clean clothes.