# Airport dogs checking our bags

Tags: najis, waswasa

Assalaamu Alaikkum..,

I'm Fathima mother of two kids and 7 months pregnant. I'm suffering with waswas problem regarding najasa.. It often comes and goes... last few days I'm having severe waswas problem with 2 issues. I use to travel vacation to my home country and some other countries as well... when I travel Sometimes, airport dogs come close to my baggage and I feel their tongue touches my bags and I feel  always my bags are unclean... so I try as much as I can not to touch anything with wet objects with my bags.. But, others don't do like that. Once My relative kept my praying mat on that bag and I'm not sure whether the musallaa wet or not... this happened a few months ago and even if I keep thinking I should not fall in to shaythan's whispering and I used the same mat to pray till I go to my country for 2 months vacation. But, when I come back I feel again this mat is dirty, I should wash it... some time I feel no it's not.. If I wash this will continue... last few days I'm praying on it... but my mind is always doubt in it... this is one issue..
another issue is I took one cloth in my bag with other cloths ( all were dry) but, when I take them all out, they were cool due to travel.. Now I feel my other clothes also become najis... I'm not sure with which cloths I kept that dirty cloth..

Last few days this 2 issues are making me mad... I'm full disturbed... I keep on asking dua from ALLAAH... Still my mind is heavy and always feeling that all are unclean.. I couldn't sleep properly.. I worry about my baby... 
Please give me a remedy.. It might look silly... But, I don't know what to do... I'm afraid something will happen to me.. My husband always say just leave it. I'm also trying. But, I couldn't do it... Should I see a doctor?

I want to know, will najis transmit from one to another even if it little wet?

Jazakallaah....

Comment: Woah!  What's the Islam-related question?

Comment: yes . See a doctor

Answer (score 2):

I keep saying that *tahara* and *najasa* have only a tangential connection to cleanness, hygiene, dirtiness and impurity. They primarily are ritual necessities!

Usually the dogs at airports don't sniff or come too close to any bag unless it has either some food they may like in it (and if they are well trained they wouldn't even do this) or it contains drugs (or any other dangerous material they might be trained on smelling it).

Let's say a dog came close to your bag and sniffed on it. Dogs basically are not impure ([Are Dogs Impure?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12189/are-dogs-impure/29760#29760))! The only thing that is reported to be impure is the spittle of a dog and again we have different opinions on that!
The qur'an and even the sunnah (see my answer on the post linked above) allows as to use dogs for hunting so they will clearly have the pray animal in their muzzles which seems contradictory to the hadith that says:

> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: The purification of the utensil belonging to any one of you, after it is licked by a dog, lies in washing it seven times, using sand for the first time.
>   (Sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/117))

So if you had any doubt that the dogs spittle is on your bag or anything you belong it is simply enough to wash it seven times or put it in the washer afterwards it will be clean. Note that the hadith was also narrated without the addition "using sand for the first time" which seems more authentic. As washing something from the spittle of a dog seems logical, even if seven times might sounds exaggerated ... also note that sand in this case may play an extra cleaning role (and Allah knows best).

Also note that leaving something outside in the sunlight is also considered as a way to take away *najassa*!

Finally note that *najassa* is a "local issue" that means only the location or object where the *najassa* is on itself is considered as *najiss* so you shouldn't worry about contamination unless you touched or moved parts of the *najassa* to a different location. Only wet *najassa* is considered as able to move from location to another or contaminate, dry not!

If you had still have any doubts you really should search a doctor!

Maybe somewhat relevant:
[Tahaara and waswas](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30452/tahaara-and-waswas/30522#30522)

[How can I clean bathroom tiles which may have semen on them?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/36447/how-can-i-clean-bathroom-tiles-which-may-have-semen-on-them/36462#36462)

[Will my pure clothes become impure by washing them in a washing machine with impure clothes?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36864/13438)